# tab pages not working with sidemenu in ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

i am new to IONIC.
I want to implement tabbed with sidemenu project.
means i have sidemenu, on clicking one of sidemenu option there will be a page having tab. i wrote code for it but pages are not redirecting of tab page.

my app.js

```
 .state('app', {
url: '/app',
abstract: true,
templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
controller: 'AppCtrl'
}) 
.state('app.tabs', {
    url: "/tabs",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.tabs.currentrides', {
    url: '/currentrides',
    views: {
      'currentrides': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/currentrides.html',
        controller: 'CurrentRidesCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.tabs.rideshistory', {
    url: '/rideshistory',
    views: {
      'rideshistory': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/rideshistory.html',
        controller: 'RidesHistoryCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

my tabs.html

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive" >

        <!-- Current Tab -->
        <ion-tab title="Current Rides" ui-href="app.tabs.currentrides">
            <ion-nav-view name="currentrides"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <!-- History Tab -->
        <ion-tab title="Rides History" ui-href="app.tabs.rideshistory">
            <ion-nav-view name="rideshistory"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

    </ion-tabs>
```

pages of tab not redirecting.

**Answer :**

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive" >

        <!-- Current Tab -->
        <ion-tab title="Current Rides" href="#/app/tabs/currentrides">
            <ion-nav-view name="currentrides"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <!-- History Tab -->
        <ion-tab title="Rides History" href="#/app/tabs/rideshistory">
            <ion-nav-view name="rideshistory"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

    </ion-tabs>
```

Comment: You should maybetry with simple `href`

Comment: after adding abstract:true to my app.tabs state it not redirecting to my tabs page

Comment: even href also not working it not getting the address of any page

Comment: and with a simple href or ui-sref ? ui-href should not exist

Comment: @DMCISSOKHO : thanks , href is works after some changes

Comment: could you post your solution ?

Comment: old `href="app.tabs.currentrides"` to new href="#/app/tabs/currentrides"  in html view

Comment: now i am facing redirection problem from same tab to one page by clicking on button i wrote in my `html` page `<button class="button button-assertive button-block center-button transparent-back" ng-click="request()">Request for Ride</button>` in my `controller.js` i wrote `$scope.request=function(){
    $state.go('app.tabs.requestforride');
  }`

Comment: and in my `app.js` i wrote `.state('app.tabs.requestforride',{
        url:'/requestforride',
        views: {
          'requestforride':{
            templateUrl: 'templates/requestforride.html',
            controller: 'RequestForRideCtrl'
          }

        }
      })`

Comment: let's tchat i will help you

Comment: could you tell me what's your error ?